# send ajax request to spring security login

Tags: jquery, ajax, spring-security

i want to do the login action with spring security using jquery ajax. here is what i have in my security config class:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(prePostEnabled=true)
public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Autowired
    private Environment env;

    @Autowired
    private UserSecurityService userSecurityService;

    @Autowired
    MyAuthenticationSuccessHandler myAuthenticationSuccessHandler;


    @Autowired
    MyAuthenticationFailureHandler myAuthenticationFailureHandler;

    private static final String SALT = "salt"; 

    @Bean
    public BCryptPasswordEncoder passwordEncoder() {
        return new BCryptPasswordEncoder(12, new SecureRandom(SALT.getBytes()));
    }

    private static final String[] PUBLIC_MATCHERS = {
            "/webjars/**",
            "/css/**",
            "/js/**",
            "/images/**",
            "/",
            "/about/**",
            "/contact/**",
            "/error/**/*",
            "/console/**",
            "/signup"
    };

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
                .authorizeRequests().
                antMatchers(PUBLIC_MATCHERS).
                permitAll().anyRequest().authenticated();

        http
                .csrf().disable().cors().disable()
                .formLogin().failureHandler(myAuthenticationFailureHandler).loginProcessingUrl("/login")
                .successHandler(myAuthenticationSuccessHandler).loginPage("/index").permitAll()
                .and()
                .logout().logoutRequestMatcher(new AntPathRequestMatcher("/logout")).logoutSuccessUrl("/index?logout").deleteCookies("remember-me").permitAll()
                .and()
                .rememberMe();
    }



    @Autowired
    public void configureGlobal(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        auth.userDetailsService(userSecurityService).passwordEncoder(passwordEncoder());
    }


}
```

MyAuthenticationSuccessHandler.java

```
@Component
public class MyAuthenticationSuccessHandler extends SimpleUrlAuthenticationSuccessHandler {

    private Log log = LogFactory.getLog(MyAuthenticationSuccessHandler.class);

    @Override
    public void onAuthenticationSuccess(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response,
                                        Authentication authentication) throws IOException, ServletException {
        // This is actually not an error, but an OK message. It is sent to avoid redirects.
        response.sendError(HttpServletResponse.SC_OK);
    }
}
```

MyAuthenticationFailureHandler.class

```
@Component
public class MyAuthenticationFailureHandler extends SimpleUrlAuthenticationFailureHandler {

    public void onAuthenticationFailure(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, AuthenticationException exception) throws IOException, ServletException {
            response.sendError(401, "Authentication Failed: " + exception.getMessage());
    }

}
```

and this is the form where i send an ajax request:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" xmlns:th="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head th:replace="common/header :: common-header"/>
<body>
<!-- Login Section -->
    <img class="img-responsive" src="/images/banner.png" alt="banner"/>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row ">
            <div class="main-center" id="main">
                <div class="bg-danger" id="wrongPass" style="display: none">
                    Invalid username and secret.
                </div>
                <div class="bg-danger" th:if="${param.logout}">
                    You have been logged out.
                </div>
                <form id="loginForm" class="form-signin" th:action="@{/index}" method="post">
                    <h2 class="form-signin-heading">Please sign in</h2>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="username" class="sr-only">Username</label>
                        <input type="text" roleId="username" class="form-control" placeholder="Username" name="username"
                               id="username"
                               required="required" autofocus="autofocus"/>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="password" class="sr-only">Password</label>
                        <input type="password" roleId="inputPassword" class="form-control" placeholder="Password"
                               id="password"
                               name="password" required="required"/>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <input type="checkbox" name="remember-me" id="remember-me"/> &nbsp; Remember me
                    </div>
                    <button id="signIn" class="btn btn-lg btn-primary btn-block" type="submit">Sign in</button>
                </form>

                <hr />

                <div class="form-group ">
                    <a id="signUp" type="submit" class="btn btn-info btn-lg btn-block login-button" th:href="@{/signup}">Sign up!</a>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

<div th:replace="common/header :: body-bottom-scripts"/>
<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('#signIn').on('click', function (e) {
            debugger;
            e.preventDefault();
            $('#wrongPass').hide();
            $.ajax({
                url: "/j_spring_security_check",
                type: 'POST',
                beforeSend: function(xhr) {
                    xhr.withCredentials = true;
                },
                data:$('#loginForm').serialize()
            }).success(function (response){
                debugger;
                console.log(response);
                $('body').load('/userFront');
            }).error(function (res, status){
                debugger;
                console.log(res);
                $('#wrongPass').show()
            });
        });
    })
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

but it doesn't work at all! and in console log i get the above html as response!

what i need is simply get something like a boolean value to indicate whether the authentication was true or not. and based on that the call back function should either load the `userFront.html` page or show the error message.

i even tried with `/index` as ajax url and also `JSON.stringify({username:...,password:...})` as json data but none of them were helpful!

any help would be appreciated as i really got stuck!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

very silly mistake guys! in `SecurityConfig` class, whatever the `loginProcessingUrl` is, the ajax request should be sent to that url. so if the `loginProcessingUrl` is `"/loginUrl"` for instance, you just need to simply change ajax url to "/loginUrl".

that's it. this is because i was trying to read many articles in SO to find my solution and nearly none of them were explaining the solution completely.

i don't know why some people spend so much time to read questions and respond to them but don't consider the fact that maybe the inquirer is a beginner, which mostly is. so they have some pre-assumptions which will lead to these situations.

most of the times problems are easy to solve, just the explanation is not decent enough!! to be able to explain correctly and thoroghly is a major skill!